# What is the difference between "Action<object?, EventArgs>" and "EventHandler(object? sender, EventArgs e)"?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, delegates

```
public delegate void Action<object?, EventArgs>(object? sender, EventArgs e);

public delegate void EventHandler(object? sender, EventArgs e);
```

What is the difference between those two lines? They seem to be functionally equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotabor's answer is basically correct, except for the reasoning:  `EventHandler` exists since .NET Framework 1.1, which did not have generics and thus also did not yet have `Action<T>`. Only fully defined delegate types where allowed.

When `Action` (with it's generic overloads) was added in .NET Framework 2.0, `EventHandler` was kept for backwards compatibility.

Comment: High mark for history knowledge!

Comment: Well in v1.0 (and later, including v1.1), the first argument was just an `object`, not an `object?`. It's also worth noting that `EventHandler` and  `Action<>` with `object` and `object?` are 4 different types and can't always be used interchangeably.

Comment: @Flydog57 Any reference for this? If I'm not mistaken, nullable reference types (`object?`) is just a compiler thing and handled by attributes. It has no impact on the generated code at all, so the types _are_ the same.

Comment: I might be wrong there. Definitely `Action` and `EventHandler` are different types, like `Predicate<T>` and `Func<T, bool>`. Easy to test though.

Answer (score 1):

If fact, there is no difference:

```
EventHandler a;
Action<object?, EventArgs> b;

void c(object? o, EventArgs e) { }

void d() {
    a = c; b = c; // no error
}
```

"EventHandler" is introduced just for convenience to use anywhere for event-related code.